# script src 302 How to find out which link redirects?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script src=https://example.com/redirect></script> redirect to ==> https://example.com/$random$/special.js
```

Suppose I connect a js that redirects me to https://example.com/$random$/special.js
How can I find out which link he redirected me to?

Comment: Find out in what way? Are you wanting to find this programmatically at runtime, or you're just wanting to find out once manually? If at runtime, in which context are you needing to detect the URL? From within the `https://example.com/$random$/special.js` script or from outside that script?

Comment: Also, if you need this from outside the script, is the original script domain in the same domain as your document or is it a third-party domain?